# Find the equation of a circle.

Tags: circles

If a circle which center is on the straight line $x-2y+3=0$ cuts both the x-axis and the y-axis, what is the equation of the circle?

ANSWER: $x^2+y^2-6x-6y+9=0$
This is rather a straightforward question but I don't know how to start...some hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does 'cuts' mean 'touches'?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I assumed so too.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the center of the circle with radius $=r$

$\implies \alpha-2\beta=3\iff \alpha=2\beta-3$

Assuming 'cuts' means 'touches', the axes are tangents of the circle.

So, the perpendicular distance(s) of each axis from the center$(2\beta-3,\beta)$ equals to the radius$(=r)$

Do you know the equation of the axes and

how to calculate the perpendicular distance of a straight line from a given point

Comment: @Sophia, We shall have $|\beta|=r=|\alpha|=|2\beta-3|$  Squaring we get $\beta^2=(2\beta-3)^2\implies \beta=?$

Comment: Okay, I'll try to solve it! ;D

Comment: @Sophia, there are two circles, right? I have used one of the two definitions of the tangent of a circle

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start with $\left(x-2a+3\right)^{2}+\left(x-a\right)^{2}=r^{2}$